# Faded pages after getting new toners for Laserjet M15w

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I have an HP M15w with 1000 text prints put through it. I noticed that the prints contrast was fading and I changed toner for the second time since I bought it. But the contrast of the prints didn't recover after changing the toner. I have found very little non-HP information on the internet on how to diagnose the problem. The information provided by HP was mainly focused on discouraging purchases of toners from other manufacturers than HP. I have tried to shake the toner and knock it on a table. In the beginning, shaking it helped a bit perhaps. I have purchased a second toner, and the problem is just as bad. Here is a picture of what a typical print looks like.
[image: Faded print]

It would be nice if there was a source of information on how to service these things such that one need not phone the printer-repair-guy every couple of months. I will accept as the answer any information that will lead to the solution of the problem.

Comment: Since shaking helped, though just for a while, you've confirmed the issue is with the toner cartridge. *Whatever* the rating, that cartridge appears to be defective. You can confirm this by substituting another cartridge... then return the bad one for refund.

Comment: I am not convinced it's the toner, because I spent $50 on a second toner (from a different seller), per your recommendation, and the problem is just the same. If you can assist with troubleshooting, it would be much appreciated. I have added additional information above.

Comment: Don't just knock the toner cartridge willy-nilly, you should shake/rock it back and forth laterally.  Inspect the drums and make sure there's no toner clumped or stuck on there along the inside edge.  After that run a cleaning page and see if that helps.

What type of copy paper are you printing on?  Make sure to never re-use any paper you've already printed on before, especially if they were printed from a laserjet printer, as the toner that's on the paper can melt and re-adhere to the printer internals, thus causing issues.

Comment: Check [these 5 causes](https://www.tonergiant.co.uk/blog/2014/10/faint-print-5-things-that-could-be-causing-your-printer-problem/). Also, some advice [from HP](https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c02011355).

Comment: Maybe it's silly to say... but are you sure that some extreme economy settings are not activated? Both in the specific program and in general on the printer. They might have been activated unnoticed even after a driver update or system crash.
  
Also, if your printer is clean, the roller may also need to be replaced after some time, not only for use but just for simple aging (even if it is more rare),

Comment: Printers are complicated (combination of digital & lots of mechnical parts), frequently have faults, & are the bane of my existence as IT support; welcome to the club! 1)If two new toners exhibit the same issue my next thought is did you change the paper you buy? 2)Did something change when these problems started (new/different paper, new PC, new area, etc.)? The next thing that is recommended to replace for print quality issues is the drum, but I am fairly certain that is bundled with your toner. Another printer company says for faint prints it's likely bad/low toner, eco/toner-saver setting

Comment: ...bad paper, humid/hot environment, or drum. Links relating to my above/previous comment: https://support.brother.com/g/b/imglist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&ptn=1 https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&ptn=1&faqid=faq00000151_029 https://computer.howstuffworks.com/laser-printer.htm/printable